# Automapping dynamic objects ignoring case of property names

Tags: automapper

How do I configure the mapper so that this works?

(i.e. the properties from the dynamic object should map to the properties of the class definition with the same letters - ignoring case)

```
public class Foo {
    public int Bar { get; set; }
    public int Baz { get; set; }
}

dynamic fooDyn = new MyDynamicObject();
fooDyn.baR = 5;
fooDyn.bAz = 6;

Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {});

Foo result = Mapper.Map<Foo>(fooDyn);
result.Bar.ShouldEqual(5);
result.Baz.ShouldEqual(6);
```

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html

Comment: @Lucian - that's where I took the example from.  the issue is that the fields of the dynamic object have to match the casing of the destination objection.

Comment: You'll have to handle that yourself in an extra step. But you don't need any reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dynamic object implements `IDictionary<string,object>` (e.g. `ExpandoObject`) then the following should work. There must be some easier way to do this as anonymous objects are mapped just fine even if the case is different.

```
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<IDictionary<string, object>, Foo>()
            .ConstructUsing(d =>
            {
                Foo foo = new Foo();

                foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo prop in typeof(Foo).GetProperties())
                {
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> entry in d)
                    {
                        if (entry.Key.ToLowerInvariant() == prop.Name.ToLowerInvariant())
                        {
                            prop.SetValue(foo, entry.Value);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                return foo;
            });
        });
```

Comment: It's strange that anon objects are mapped fine regardless of the casing...  I guess I have to create a map for every type I want to map, but I've googled around and found nothing, so thanks!  this should work for now.

Answer (score 0):

AutoMapper allows you to configure explicit member mapping on the map configuration in this style:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {

                var dynamicMap = cfg.CreateMap<IDictionary<string, object>, SomethingDTO>();
                dynamicMap.ForAllMembers((expression) => expression.MapFrom(source =>
                    source.ContainsKey(expression.DestinationMember.Name.Substring(0, 1).ToLower()
                                                                            + expression.DestinationMember.Name.Substring(1))
                    ? source[expression.DestinationMember.Name.Substring(0, 1).ToLower()
                                    + expression.DestinationMember.Name.Substring(1)]  : null
                ));
            });
```

For mapping a dynamic/expando object that is camel case to an type with pascal case members you could use ForAllMembers on the the explicit map configuration. Possible use case: json payloads to DTO.

In comparison to the other answer (which also works) this approach allows you to continue to benefit and use all the other map features and configuration.